# How to run R script from Windows CMD that includes slashes in file paths?

Tags: r, windows, cmd

There is a plenty of questions on running R script from CMD, but none of them seem to address the following issue. How do I do this, if my R script, which I want to run, contains some variables that are paths. I mean for instance, my script is reading from or writing to specific files like that:

```
readxl("~/user/foo/sheet1.xlsx")
#
#doing something
#
writexl("~/user/bar/sheet2.xlsx")
```

So if I try to run this from command line, I am getting errors that path is not found, because there are backslashes in cmd, so it says something like `The directory "C:\users\user/foo/sheet1.xlsx"` is not found.

So is there a way to overcome this somehow? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Write the path like this:

```
'"~/user/foo/sheet1.xlsx"'
```

Comment: Would that also work if I perform operations with 'paste'? Like `paste( '"~user/foo"', '"bar/sheet1.xlsx"', sep = "/")`? I also has a path variable stored `p <- path.expand("~")` and also using it with `paste`, like `paste(p, "/foo/bar")`. Is it possible to adjust these parts also somehow?